# Properly adding array to array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to put an array inside an array (inside an array) using PHP.

```
$objectArray = array ('id' => $place, 'name'=>$placeName, array ('contact_info'=> array ('phone'=>$phone, 'email'=>$email,'website'=>$website)));
$data3 = array('place' => $objectArray);
$data_json = json_encode($data3);
echo $data_json;
```

This gives me something like this:

```
{
"place": {
    "0": {
        "contact_info": {
            "phone": "513-555-1212",
            "email": "jmr@example.com",
            "website": "https://example.com"
        }
    },
    "id": "999999",
    "name": "My House",
 }
}
```

What I'm looking for as an end product is:

```
{
"place": {
    "contact_info": {
        "phone": "513-555-1212",
        "email": "jmr@example.com",
        "website": "https://example.com"
        },
    "id": "999999",
    "name": "My House",
 }
```

I need to not have the '0' and the `contact info` part under `place`

Comment: eliminate the cast `array('contact_info' ..)` and let it just `contact_info =>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purposes `$objectArray` should have this structure:

```
$objectArray = array ( 
    'id' => $place, 
    'name'=>$placeName, 
    'contact_info'=> array ('phone'=>$phone, 'email'=>$email,'website'=>$website)
);
```

So, `contact_info` should be on the **same** level as `id` and `name`, without new `array`.

Comment: Notice how writing the code using this format (instead of oneliner) helps seeing this kind of problems easier.

Comment: Thanks! This worked! @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo Great point...something to keep in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this

```
$objectArray = array (
   'id' => '99999', 
   'name'=>'My House', 
   'contact_info' => array (
       'phone'=>'513-555-1212',
       'email'=>'jmr@example.com',
       'website'=>'https://example.com'
   )
);
$data3 = array('place' => $objectArray);
$data_json = json_encode($data3);
echo $data_json;
```

Remove the array part placed before 'contact_info' so they come at same level.